# Execute background external program

Tags: php, windows, powershell, background-process

If I have a script like this:

```
<?php
system('notepad');
echo "END\n";
```

It opens the Notepad program, but the script stops until Notepad is ended. I would like to open the program in the background. I tried this:

```
system('notepad &');
```

but it the process continues to block the script. I think it's because my shell is PowerShell, not Bash or similar. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you can use `proc_open`:

```
<?php
$a_desc = [];
$a_pipe = [];
$r = proc_open('notepad', $a_desc, $a_pipe);
echo "END\n";
proc_close($r);
```

When you use `proc_open`, PHP will only wait for the process to terminate if you
also call `proc_close`. So in the above script, the `END` will go ahead and
print, but the script will still hang after that. If you want to totally forget
about the process, you can omit the `proc_close`:

```
<?php
$a_desc = [];
$a_pipe = [];
proc_open('notepad', $a_desc, $a_pipe);
echo "END\n";
```

In general you want to call `proc_close`, as if your external command produces
output, then that output would likely print after any internal `echo`
statements you have.

https://php.net/function.proc-close